# I want to check is a certain variable which the user will input is in a filtered list, using javaScript

Tags: javascript

I am programming a travel planning app. the user will input the state he or she is traveling to, and the app will use a data table that contains the states and their corresponding cases, to see if the state has a number of cases less than 100,000. If so, it would setProperty to covid risky or safe.

here is my code:

```
 function checkingUpdate() {
  var filteredCasesList = [];
  var filteredStatesList = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < cases.length; i++) {
    var casesLength = (cases[i]).length;
    if (casesLength <= 100000) {
      appendItem(filteredStatesList, states[i]);
      appendItem(filteredCasesList, cases[i]);
}

onEvent("screen2ToScreen3Button", "click", function( ) {
  var state = getText("stateInput");
  if (state in (filteredStatesList) ) {
    setProperty("yesOrNoLabel", "text", "Covid Okay!");
  } else {
    setProperty("yesOrNoLabel", "text", "Covid Risky, stay safe!");
  }
});
```

Comment: This seems like it should work, but you asked this question so we are assuming it doesn't. Consider giving us info about what you *want* to happen and what *is* happening.

Comment: If cases are less than 100,000 I want the app to change the property of yesOrNoLabel to "Covid Okay!" if more, that it should change the label to "Covid Risky, stay safe!" But right not for all state inputs, it prints "covid Risky, stay safe"

Comment: Ok, we know that part. Now, we need to know *what is happening*, or more importantly *why doesn't this work*. There are a few functions here that I do not recognize, like `onEvent()` and `setProperty()`. From the looks of it, `filteredStatesList` is an object. Your code *should* work properly from what I see,  but you posted this question...  which gives the assumption that *something* isn't working. So, can you tell us what *isn't* happening, or, any errors that are appearing?

Comment: It seems you are missing some  closing `}`. Also are you missing the function call for  checkingUpdate() function before the event that needs filteredStatesList?

Comment: @Shwetapatel that *does* seems like the problem here. Although I wonder if we aren't seeing their full code so they might not have presented the code as it is in their program.

Comment: @Shwetapatel no, I included it and the complete program has the curly brackets. I have shown one part.

Comment: @Reality in the "in" function correct how else would you check if a string is part of a list

Comment: Ok, then why doesn't it work? What does it do *instead* of what you want it to. That is what we are asking for here. It seems like your code should work to us or at least it is harder to find out what it is *because* you don't give us the unexpected results of running your program.

Comment: @Reality If cases are less than 100,000 I want the app to change the property of yesOrNoLabel to "Covid Okay!" if more, that it should change the label to "Covid Risky, stay safe!" But right not for all state inputs, it prints "covid Risky, stay safe" –

Comment: Can you try  and check  ```if (filteredStatesList.includes(state)) ``` instead of ```if (state in (filteredStatesList) )``` ?

Comment: @Shwetapatel It said it is not a function. any other suggestions? But thank you for your help

Comment: We shouldn't keep extended conversation in comments, but why are you comparing `cases[i].length`? Why not just count the cases total there and if the cases are greater than 100,000 just append the state to `filteredStatesList`. Also note that JavaScript is case-sensitive so if the state registered is "Maryland" with a capital "M" and someone types in "maryland" it won't match.

Comment: @Reality I changed is to 'cases < 100000'  but it still is not working.